# "undownvoted" rather than "removed" in reputation history?

Tags: support, bug, reputation-history

I down-voted the two non-answers to this none-question when I came across them yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661637

The posts have now been removed, but I notice in my reputation history something unusual that I have not seen before:

[image]

Why does this show as "undownvoted" rather than "removed" (like the post above it)?

I certainly didn't undownvote those posts.

Comment: Looks wrong.  Those posts were not removed the normal way however.  It wasn't the poster that removed it and it wasn't removed because the question was deleted.

Comment: I assumed it was a review queue thing that removed the posts. But I notice also they're still links, when it would usually be text (as in other +1 shown).

Comment: (I assumed if it had've been moderator involvement, they wouldn't have left the question behind)

Comment: There was a moderator involved, and they did.

Comment: @Fred oh. Ok. I don't have 10k on SO so could not see what happened to the answers. :/ even then, I would have expected "removed" so curious what the difference is for.

Comment: I guess it's because of [rejected migrations](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296283/3488231)?

Comment: @ace since when this meta question was asked, it was still open on stack overflow, no.

Comment: One was deleted by a moderator, the other was _not_.  The question was deleted by 10k users.  That's ... definitely odd (not the deletions, but the 'undownvoted' bit).  The downvotes did indeed go away - both answers are 0(+0/-0) not -1 or 0(+1/-1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two *possible* reasons, but I can't personally confirm either.

After you downvoted the OP's two answers and (I assume) the question, the serial voting detection mechanism detected that as serial voting, and reversed the votes. Not saying the votes were unwarranted by any means, just that the mechanism recognized a pattern and took action.

Seems like it'd take more votes than that (did you maybe dv his only other question too?), but then I have no idea what the threshold or various factors are that play into the automated reversal mechanism.

Another (*highly* unlikely) reason might be that an employee got involved. I only mention it because Anna Lear had made mention of it awhile back, in a comment under [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141305/166022):

> Moderators can't reverse anyone's votes. We (employees) can, but we don't make a habit of it and it's not exactly an easy button beside every post.

However, there's nothing in this instance that suggests they stepped in. The more likely scenario of the two (assuming it's not a bug) would be the serial-voting-reversal mechanism.

Comment: I possibly dv the question as well, which would make it three posts in a short time frame. I don't think their other question is good but can't remember if I downvoted it. Your suggestion makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I thought the serial voting check was more when someone would downvote a specific person. And even then, 3 votes isn't so much. I it's on the same person I admit there's a weird coincidence but in this case not so much. Maybe the system should ignore questions that receive flags in that calculation.